# SQL Query, taking hours to finish executing

Tags: sql-server, performance

i've been currently breaking my mind trying to reduce the execute time of the next query. I've done a lot of research, but i've not found anything that can help me. This query takes about six hours to finish executing. One main problem that i have, is that i can't use indexes, so yeah, that's a big deal.

What i think, is that since i'm not a sql expert, maybe i'm not using the best practices to achieve the result that i want from this query.

I'm working with a lot of joins, aggregations, temp tables, etc. Maybe, there are workarounds that due to my low experience, i'm not aware of. So, maybe you could help me.

```
SELECT  
    ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY C.CourseKey) AS 'RowNumber',
    C.CourseKey,
    COALESCE(DCC.College,C.College) 'College',
    COALESCE(DCC.Department,C.Department) 'Department',
    COALESCE(DCC.CourseNumber,C.CourseNumber) 'CourseNumber',
    COALESCE(DCC.[Subject],C.[Subject]) 'Subject',
    C.Description + ' ('+C.BatchUID+')' as 'CourseSimple',
    COALESCE(DCC.[Description],C.[Description]) as 'Section',
    F.AcademicYear,
    F.Description as 'Term',
    --E.Description as 'Instructor',
    B.Description as 'Item',
    B.CourseItemGroup,
    G.FullDate,
    C.StartDate,
    DU.UserKey,
    SUM(A.CourseItemMinutes) AS 'Minutes',
    SUM(A.CourseItemAccesses) As 'Items'
Into #CourseDesign
FROM Final.FactCourseItemActivity A
INNER JOIN Final.DimCourseItemType B on A.CourseItemTypeKey = B.CourseItemTypeKey
INNER JOIN Final.DimCourse C on A.CourseKey = C.CourseKey
INNER JOIN Final.DimUser DU on A.UserKey = DU.UserKey
INNER JOIN Final.FactStudentCourseSummary FSCS on FSCS.UserSourceKey = DU.SourceKey
                                                    And FSCS.CourseKey = A.CourseKey
                                                    And A.TermKey = FSCS.TermKey
INNER JOIN CustomFinal.DimCourseCustom DCC on FSCS.CourseCustomKey = DCC.CourseCustomKey
INNER JOIN Final.DimTerm F on A.TermKey = F.TermKey
INNER JOIN Final.DimDate G on A.DateKey = G.DateKey
WHERE A.CourseItemMinutes > 0
GROUP BY 
    C.CourseKey,
    COALESCE(DCC.College,C.College),
    COALESCE(DCC.Department,C.Department),
    COALESCE(DCC.CourseNumber,C.CourseNumber),
    COALESCE(DCC.[Subject],C.[Subject]),
    C.Description + ' ('+C.BatchUID+')',
    COALESCE(DCC.[Description],C.[Description]),
    F.AcademicYear,
    F.Description,
    --E.Description,
    B.Description,
    B.CourseItemGroup,
    G.FullDate,
    C.StartDate,
    DU.UserKey


Select 
       A.RowNumber,
       A.Coursekey,
       A.College,
       A.Department,
       A.CourseNumber,
       A.[Subject],
       A.CourseSimple,
       A.Section,
       A.AcademicYear,
       A.Term,
       A.Item,
       A.CourseItemGroup,
       A.FullDate,
       H.WeekLevel,
       SUM(A.[Minutes]) 'Minutes',
       COUNT(Distinct A.UserKey) 'Students',
       SUM(A.Items) 'Items'
Into #FinalTable
From #CourseDesign A
     INNER JOIN Final.DimDayOfTerm H on 
                case 
                    when A.FullDate is null then -2
                    when DATEDIFF(dd,A.StartDate,A.FullDate)+1 < 0 then -1
                    else DATEDIFF(dd,A.StartDate,A.FullDate)
                end = H.DayOfTermKey
Group by 
         A.RowNumber,
         A.Coursekey,
         A.College,
         A.Department,
         A.CourseNumber,
         A.[Subject],
         A.CourseSimple,
         A.Section,
         A.AcademicYear,
         A.Term,
         A.Item,
         A.CourseItemGroup,
         A.FullDate,
         H.WeekLevel


Select A.RowNumber,
       A.Coursekey,
       A.College,
       A.Department,
       A.CourseNumber,
       A.[Subject],
       A.CourseSimple,
       A.Section,
       A.AcademicYear,
       A.Term,
       A.Item,
       A.CourseItemGroup,
       A.FullDate,
       A.WeekLevel,
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + DU2.Description
       FROM #FinalTable AS A2
               LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomFinal.ReportingInstructors RI2
                        on A2.CourseKey = RI2.CourseKey
               LEFT OUTER JOIN Final.DimUser DU2
                        on RI2.UserKey = DU2.UserKey
               WHERE ((A.RowNumber IS NULL AND A2.RowNumber IS NULL) OR A.RowNumber = A2.RowNumber)
       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS Instructor,
       A.Minutes,
       A.Students,
       A.Items
From #FinalTable A
LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomFinal.ReportingInstructors RI on A.CourseKey = RI.CourseKey
LEFT OUTER JOIN Final.DimUser DU on RI.UserKey = DU.UserKey

Group by 
         A.RowNumber,
         A.Coursekey,
         A.College,
         A.Department,
         A.CourseNumber,
         A.[Subject],
         A.CourseSimple,
         A.Section,
         A.AcademicYear,
         A.Term,
         A.Item,
         A.CourseItemGroup,
         A.FullDate,
         A.WeekLevel,
         A.Minutes,
         A.Students,
         A.Items
```

Comment: How many rows are you inserting into your temp tables, typically? And why can't you put indexes on those to help speed things up, if there are a lot of rows?

Comment: Are you using this SELECT as in INSERT INTO?

Comment: if you'd like to get even a resistance of a helpful answer, you need to post an execution plan https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Seconding the question - why cant you use indexes. Are there indexes on any of the tables? And have you looked at the sql profiler to see which part of the proc is slow? I'm guessing the last correlated sub query wont be great - I'd refactor that out into something I join on. But without knowing which part of the query is bad its hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to transfer a large amount of data from one database to another. I had to figure out a way that wouldn't cripple my source SQL Server when INSERTing data into the destination.

Here's what I did to accomplish this. If you're doing something similar, perhaps this will help you too.

```
insert_more_rows:

    INSERT INTO MyDestination (
        cols ...
    )
    SELECT TOP 1000
        cols ...
    FROM MySource
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS ( condition to exclude existing data )...

IF ( ( some condition to determine there are more rows ) > 0 )
    GOTO insert_more_rows;
```

This worked well for me and cut down the time involved drastically.